# Locked myself out while changing SSH config

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

As I was adding a new user to my Ubuntu Server installation, I made sure he was mentioned in the `AllowUsers` parameter in my `sshd_config`. While doing that, I accidentally somehow managed to get my server to refuse my own login attempts. Is it possible that I locked myself out?

The newly created user is logging in fine, however he doesn't have any `sudo` rights, therefore I am not able to alter my SSH config. How do I regain control of my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the new user, can you `su - otheruser` to become your other user and then `sudo` from there?

Answer (score 0):

During boot, press and hold the left Shift key, and you should see the GRUB menu.
Select the entry containing (recovery mode) and wait.
You should now be presented a menu. Select:

```
remount    Remount / read/write and mount all other file systems
```

wait for your file systems to get mounted with read/write permissions, then press Enter.

If this option won't go, you can solve this entering with the 'root' option and typing mount command to use the system partition this way:

```
mount -o remount /dev/sda3
```

You can check out which is your system partition with 'fsck' command or viewing /etc/mtab.

Now another menu comes up. Select:

```
root       Drop to root shell prompt
```

Now re-add your user to the admin group (for Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier):

```
adduser <USERNAME> admin
```

Or to the sudo group (for Ubuntu 12.04 and later):

```
adduser <USERNAME> sudo
```

Reboot and you should be able to use sudo again.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, however, `su - myusername` already did the trick :)